# Using regex to match keywords in DF

Tags: python, pandas

Good morning all I am struggling a bit with regex :(

Scenario: I have loaded an excel file into Pandas as DF to enable me to search for keywords across multiple columns.

Data:
Columns include title, scope, description and review. There are 6 keywords I need to search for.

Current approach:
Using `numpy` where `str` contains I have found matches but these are partial matches within other strings. I need to find only whole words. The below works but as I said will also identify matches within strings such as 'booking' or 'training'. I need to find a way to only find 'book' or 'train'.

```
keywords = ['book','train','job']
df["NewValue"] = np.where((df['title'].str.contains('|'.join(keywords))) 
(df['scope'].str.contains('|'.join(keywords))) | 
(df['description'].str.contains('|'.join(keywords)))| 
(df['review'].str.contains('|'.join(keywords))),1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use word boundary `\b` in raw string

```py
keywords = ['book','train','job']
cols = ['title', 'scope', 'description', 'review']

m = df[cols].apply(lambda col: col.str.contains(r'\b' + '|'.join(keywords) + r'\b')).any(axis=1)

df['NewValue'] = np.where(m,1,0)
# or
df['NewValue'] = m.astype(int)
```

To extract matched word, you can use

```py
out = (pd.concat([df[col].str.extract(r'\b(' + '|'.join(keywords) + r')\b')
                  for col in cols], axis=1)
       .groupby(level=0, axis=1).first())
```

Comment: Thanks for this, really simplified a potentially complex piece of code, compared to other things I have tried. Is there a way to pick out which keyword(s) was/were matched for each row?

Comment: @fromthedark See the update